# Interrupt-handling within kernel-module: request_irq() returns -22, Invalid Parameter

Tags: c, linux-kernel, interrupt

I'm trying to set up an interrupt-handler within a kernel-module that gets triggered by a gpio-interrupt, but it seems that I don't use the `request_irq()`-function right...
I'm getting my irq-number via `gpio_to_irq()` and this seems to work.
Then I'm calling

```
request_irq(irqNumber, handler, 0, "GPIO_Test", NULL);
```

but It returns -22, Invalid parameters.
I think it might be the handler-function because I'm not sure about it's signature - Sometimes it's defined as `void handler (int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)`, sometimes as `static irqreturn_t handler(int irq, void *data)` - Which one is the correct one to use in this case and why are there these two totally different variations?
I tried both, but always got the same Invalid-parameters-error.

The compiler gives me a warning about the return-type of my handler-function: 
when using:

```
static irqreturn_t handler(int irq, void *data)
{
    /*interrupt-handling*/

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

> »irq_handler_t« expected, but argument has type »enum irqreturn_t (* (*)(int,  void *))(int,  void *)«

...and when using:

```
void handler (int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs){/*interrupt-handling*/}
```

> »irq_handler_t« expected, but argument has type »void (*)(int,  void *, struct pt_regs *)«

Thank you for your support ;)

Comment: Handler return type `void` hasn't been valid since the 2.4 kernel series (or sometime in the 2.5 development series). Kernel versions 2.6.0 to 2.6.18 inclusive used `irqreturn_t (*handler)(int, void *, struct pt_regs *)`. Kernel versions 2.6.19 onwards use `irqreturn_t (*handler)(int, void *)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So I will continue to use the latest version - But the problem with the invalid parameters still exists. Any ideas?

Comment: As @lan mentioned you should change your irq handler signature to `irqreturn_t (*handler)(int, void *, struct pt_regs *)`..

Comment: @Sridhar Thanks again - I changed my code to match the signature, but still getting the same error as I said... My current code looks like: `static irqreturn_t handler (int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs) { /*handle interrupt */ return IRQ_HANDLED; }` And the function call: `request_irq(irqNumber, handler, 0, "GPIO_Test", NULL);`
...I can't spot any obvious mistakes - you? Thanks so far ;)

Answer (score 4):

The issue (`-EINVAL`) isn't being caused by the `handler`, as there's no way for the kernel to determine its signature at runtime.

Also, `handler` is never called while requesting an IRQ via `request_irq()` (unless `CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ_FIXME` is defined, and [with the wrong signature] that would only lead to undefined behaviour AFTER parameter validation, not before, so it would be very unlikely to return an `-EINVAL` at this point).

There are 4 key points that are validated before an IRQ is properly setup:

- **`irqflags`** - You've none set, that passes the check.
- **`irq_to_desc()`** - Will perform a lookup over `irq_desc_tree` for `irq`. Will return `-EINVAL` if not found. Otherwise, returns a pointer to an irq descriptor structure (`struct irq_desc *`)
- **`irq_settings_can_request()`** - Check if the IRQ can be requested. You can easily rule out this by calling `int can_request_irq(unsigned int irq, unsigned long irqflags)` **before** `request_irq()`.
- **`handler`** - Will check if `handler` is `NULL`. In your case, it is not.

So basically you've only two possible checks that may be causing the issue, and one of them you can rule out using `can_request_irq()` before calling `request_irq()`, but, unfortunately, this won't be possible to do under a module, because `can_request_irq` symbol isn't exported.

But if you've the patience and the time, you can build a new image with that code built-in, just see if `can_request_irq()` check passes. If it does, the only check that is causing the issue is `irq_to_desc()`, meaning that `irq` is invalid.

Can't extend this answer much more, as there's no more information I can work with from your question, but I hope it helps you to get in the right track.

By the way, just to point out the `typedef` of `irq_handler_t` in the case it may be useful:

`include/linux/interrupt.h:92` (on 4.5 tree):

```
typedef irqreturn_t (*irq_handler_t)(int, void *);
```

Comment: Thank you @pah, this explanation is extremely helpful! - I tried using `can_request_irq()`, but It seems that I can't use it because I'm on an arm-typed architecture and this function is only defined on the i386 and x86_64 architectures. (_Unknown symbol can_request_irq (err 0)_)
...Sorry that I forgot to tell you about the architecture in my question. Is there any other way to find out which of these functions causes the problem?
Looks like I can't call `irq_to_desc()` or `irq_settings_can_request()` directly.

Comment: @DocValle What's the kernel version you're working on?

Comment: I'm using the CHIP [https://getchip.com/](https://getchip.com/) with CHIP-OS 4.4.11. It's a custom linux based on debian. I'm not sure how to find the underlaying kernel-version: `uname -a` gives me `Linux chip 4.4.11-ntc #1 SMP Sat May 28 00:27:07 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux` and `cat /proc/version` shows: `Linux version 4.4.11-ntc (bamboo@ip-172-31-17-100) (gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu1) ) #1 SMP Sat May 28 00:27:07 UTC 2016`

Comment: `can_request_irq()` is generic, but the problem is that it is not exported to modules, so there's no way to use it there...  My bad, forgot about the question title `kernel-module`. Anyway, I'll see if there's an alternative way to test that from a module.

Comment: Okay, looks like 4.4.11 is the actual kernel-version it's using - my fault, thought this was just the version of there CHIP-OS...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not being able to find a way to distinguish a *failed irq lookup* from a *non-requestable irq* under a kernel module code, only as kernel *built-in* code as stated on the answer (I'll edit the answer to point that out). Meanwhile, can you provide a snippet around your `gpio_to_irq()` code?

Comment: currently it looks like:
`for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1)
{
 error = gpio_to_irq(gpios[i].gpio);
 if (error < 0)
 {
  printk (KERN_ERR "GPIO_Test: Unable to request IRQ-Number: %d\n", error);
  goto fail1;
 }
 inputIrqs[i] = error;
  error = request_irq(inputIrqs[i], handler, 0, "GPIO_Test", NULL);
 if(error) {
  printk(KERN_ERR "GPIO_Test: Unable to set up IRQ: %d\n", error);
  goto fail1;
 }
}`
inputIrqs[] is an int array to store all 8 irqNumbers I want to set up...

Comment: Can you try to use `free_irq(inputIrqs[i], NULL)` before `request_irq()`? Also, is it failing for every IRQ ? Or just only one?

Comment: `free_irq(inputIrqs[i])` didn't change anything. It fails for the first IRQ (i=0) and stops. None of my error-checks gets triggered. I load the module with `insmod GPIO_Test.ko` and this gives me this message in the terminal: `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module GPIO_Test.ko: Invalid parameters` -> `dmesg shows GPIO_Test: Unable to set up IRQ: -22`
...I test-printed the irqNumber received from the `gpio_to_irq()`-function, it was 106, seems ok.
Thanks so far for your help! ;)

Comment: Humm... This is becoming a mystery for me. If I were you, I would debug it directly in the kernel code instead of a module, as there are plenty of other interfaces that would help to get to the root cause. One other thing that crossed my mind was trying to set the irq type before `request_irq()` with something similar to `set_irq_type(inputIrqs[i], IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING);` (or any other appropriate type for your case), but I'm not aware that irq type is evaluated during IRQ handler setup, so the precedence should not matter.

Comment: For some reason my compiler doesn't know the `set_irq_type()`-function: `Implicit declaration of function »set_irq_type« [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]` ...I think I don't know enough about the linux kernel to work outside a module. What I wanted to do was an input-device which uses some Buttons on the GPIO-Pins as "keyboard". If Interrupts don't want to work I will poll the values 50 times a second or something like this to get it working... Not very elegant though. :/

Comment: You need to include `linux/irq.h` when using `set_irq_type()`. Anyway, yes, not a very elegant solution when GPIO can be IRQ mapped and handled. I'm sorry, but I don't really know what's happening there without doing some extensive debugging. Maybe some other SO user can help you better, so I recommend you to clear the 'accepted answer' tick from this answer, as if it is marked as accepted, few users will ever open and look at it again.

Comment: I actually did include `linux/irq.h` - Thanks for your time anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [`request_any_context_irq`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-request-any-context-irq.html) API ([patch](https://lwn.net/Articles/375463/)) will automatically handle the case if your interrupt line is nested and reuest a threaded handler. Since you cannot access `irq_settings_can_request` from a module this is worth using before adding instrumentation.

> This call allocates interrupt resources and enables the interrupt line
> and IRQ handling. It selects either a hardirq or threaded handling
> method depending on the context.
>
> On failure, it returns a negative value. On success, it returns either
> IRQC_IS_HARDIRQ or IRQC_IS_NESTED.